# How to know if the phone is charging

Tags: java, android

i need to know (throught my app) if the Android device is charging. Any ideas? thanks

Answer (score 9):

One thing I found out is that if your phone has 100% battery level you won't get the charging notification.  Some people mean charging and others mean when it has external power, whether its 100% or not.  I lumped these into one and if any condition is true then I return true.

```
public static boolean isPhonePluggedIn(Context context){
    boolean charging = false;

    final Intent batteryIntent = context.registerReceiver(null, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));
    int status = batteryIntent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_STATUS, -1);
    boolean batteryCharge = status==BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_CHARGING;

    int chargePlug = batteryIntent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_PLUGGED, -1);
    boolean usbCharge = chargePlug == BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_USB;
    boolean acCharge = chargePlug == BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_AC;

    if (batteryCharge) charging=true;
    if (usbCharge) charging=true;
    if (acCharge) charging=true; 

    return charging;
}
```

Comment: very nice. tested and works on Samsung A13 in 2022

Answer (score 5):

Here's the code that worked:

```
Intent bat = loader.registerReceiver(null, new
        IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));
int level = bat.getIntExtra("level", 0);
int scale = bat.getIntExtra("scale", 100);
return level * 100 / scale;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static boolean isBatteryCharging(Context context){
    // Check battery sticky broadcast
    final Intent batteryIntent = context.registerReceiver(null, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));
    return (batteryIntent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_STATUS, -1) == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_CHARGING);
}
```